# Sizeof in c porting to Java

Tags: java, c, serialization, fseek

I have a code in C like this

```
skip=(unsigned long) (st_row-1)*tot_numcols;
fseek(infile,sizeof(cnum)*skip,0);
```

Now i have to port it into Java How can I do That.The "cnum" is a Structure in C so I created a class in Java.But about that fseek how can i point to the exact position in File in Java.

Comment: [`FileChannel.position`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position(long)) ought to do the trick.

Comment: yes It is the only way to to point in a file in Java but what about the size it should move?I dont know how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Your C design is broken, and you can't do what you apparently want in Java.

It appears that you're storing information out of C structs by blindly dumping the pointer to disk. In addition to being difficult to debug, it's prone to break completely with any change that makes the compiler decide to pack the struct differently, including in particular compiling identical code for 32-bit and 64-bit or little- and big-endian targets. Instead, you should always explicitly serialize structured data. Human-readable formats are best unless there's a very large amount of data.

Java simply doesn't permit this kind of attempt. The Java memory model explicitly hides information about runtime memory packing, and the JVM has wide latitude to organize memory management as it sees fit.

Instead, define a clear format for saving your data, including endianness, and use that from both languages.

Comment: Or better yet: Use one of the existing, battle tested serialization formats with bindings/libraries existing for C and Java.

Comment: @datenwolf .. or if you are going to do it yourself, read how these libraries work, before trying to invent a better wheel.